# How to remove box shadow of material UI accordion component in react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to implement accordion using Material UI.

Here is the code:

```
      <Accordion>
            <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />} aria-controls="panel1a-content" id="panel1a-header">
                <Typography>Accordion 1</Typography>
            </AccordionSummary>
            <AccordionDetails>
                <Typography>Lorem ipsum</Typography>
                <Typography>Lorem ipsum</Typography>
                <Typography>Lorem ipsum</Typography>
            </AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
```

Here is what I get as output

[image]

As one can see there is a `box shadow` around the accordion and I want to remove it.
After inspecting the component I was able to find the class responsible for the `box shadow`.

[image]

When I disable the `box shadow` the shadow around the accordion disappears.
I followed the MUI documentation on [how to customize MUI component](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/).

Here is my code:

```
      <Accordion sx={{ "& .MuiPaper-root-MuiAccordion-root": { boxShadow: "none" } }}>
            <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />} aria-controls="panel1a-content" id="panel1a-header">
                <Typography>Accordion 1</Typography>
            </AccordionSummary>
            <AccordionDetails>
                <Typography>Lorem ipsum</Typography>
                <Typography>Lorem ipsum</Typography>
                <Typography>Lorem ipsum</Typography>
            </AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
```

But the changes don't happen. Please guide me if I am missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set `elevation` prop to zero.

```
<Accordion elevation={0}>...</Accordion>
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution. I checked the documentation but I didn't find anything about ``elevation`` props. Please can you tell me how you found the solution?

Comment: Read carefully the first line in [Props](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/accordion/#props) chapter: Props of the **Paper** component are also available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sx prop simply as follows:

```
    <Accordion sx={{ boxShadow: 'none' }}>
        <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />} aria-controls="panel1a-content" id="panel1a-header">
            <Typography>Accordion 1</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
            <Typography>Lorem ipsum</Typography>
            <Typography>Lorem ipsum</Typography>
            <Typography>Lorem ipsum</Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
    </Accordion>
```